# What else can i do 'sleep' when the sleep() can't work well with alarm?

Tags: perl, sleep, alarm

There are many documents say "you should avoid using sleep with alarm, since many systems use alarm for the sleep implementation". And actually, I'm suffering with this problem.
So does anyone can help me that what else i can do 'sleep' when the sleep() can't work well with alarm? I have already tried 'usleep' of the Time::HiRes module, and select() function. But they didn't work either.

Comment: Out of curiosity, on what system are you finding that `sleep` and `alarm` are incompatible?

Comment: @mob, from `man alarm` on a Linux box I am logged into: "sleep() may be implemented using SIGALRM; mixing calls to alarm() and sleep() is a bad idea." This applies to the C library call, but I believe Perl is just wrapping the C functions for `alarm()` and `sleep()`.

Comment: Your question doesn't describe the symptoms you're having. Most of the answerers have surmised that you're having problems because sleep is being interrupted by alarm. However, your question doesn't say this.

Comment: I'd also like to know what system you're on where this is incompatible. @Ven'Tatsu, the documentation you reference is boilerplate and doesn't necessarily apply to the system you're on. My system has the same documentation and yet sleep is not implemented using alarm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`AnyEvent`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?AnyEvent%3a%3aIntro):

```
use AnyEvent;

my $cv = AnyEvent->condvar;
my $wait_one_and_a_half_seconds = AnyEvent->timer(
    after => 1.5,
    cb => sub { $cv->send }
);     
# now wait till our time has come
$cv->recv;
```

Answer (score 5):

Seeing as you're being interrupted by alarms, and so can't reliably use sleep() or select(), I suggest using Time::HiRes::gettimeofday in combination with select().

Here's some code that I've not tested.  It should resist being interrupted by signals, and will sleep for the desired number of seconds plus up to 0.1 seconds.  If you're willing to burn more CPU cycles doing nothing productive, you can make the resolution much better:

```
...
alarm_resistant_sleep(5); # sleep for 5 seconds, no matter what
...

use Time::HiRes;

sub alarm_resistant_sleep {
  my $end = Time::HiRes::time() + shift();
  for (;;) {
    my $delta = $end - Time::HiRes::time();
    last if $delta <= 0;
    select(undef, undef, undef, $delta);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, code above is working, except `Time::HiRes::Time()` should be `Time::HiRes::time()`. It is a nice solution. Thanks.

Comment: Fixed the typo, made it more precise, and made it wake up less often. It should probably only loop if `$!{EINTR}` is true.

Comment: This example isn't working for me. In other words the sleep gets interrupted by an alarm that I call before the call to alarm_resistant_sleep(5). I wonder if it is because my system doesn't implement sleep via alarm. @ikegami, it looks like you got this to work. What system were you on?

Comment: @benrifkah, This solution (before or after my edit) has nothing to do with how `sleep` is implemented. You could replace `select` with `sleep` and you would get the same result (although with less precision since `sleep` only works with seconds). This solution is for when the problem is interruptions caused by having signal handlers. System calls are interrupted and return error EINTR when a signal comes in and you have handlers to handle it in order to give the code a chance to handle the signal. But it means you need to resume/repeat the interrupted call after the signal is handled.

Comment: @ikegami, thanks for the elaboration. If I understand you correctly this code doesn't keep a sleep from being interrupted, rather it continues sleeping the right amount of time after an interruption.

Comment: @benrifkah, Correct, but that's not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can sleep on a new process via `system`:

```
system ( "sleep", 5 );
```

Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: Yes, this is now how I work around. But It seems can't cross-platform. Is there a native way?

Answer (score 1):

When using (from [MySQL forum](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?51,256433,256478))

```
use Sys::SigAction qw( set_sig_handler );
eval {
  my $hsig = set_sig_handler( 'ALRM', sub { my $canceled = 1; die; }, { mask=>[ qw( INT ALRM ) ] ,safe => 0 } );
  alarm($timeout);
  ...
  alarm(0);
}
```

I noticed that any subsequent calls made to `sleep($delay)` with `$timeout` shorter than `$delay` would end up with the script execution being terminated, and the print of "`Alarm clock`".

The workaround I've found is to call `alarm()` again but with an improbably large value (3600), and cancel that alarm right after.

```
eval {
  alarm(3600);
  print " .... Meeeep ....";  # Some trace
  alarm(0); 
};
```

Then I can use `sleep()` with no interference anymore.

Example below (live code snippet):

```
sub unmesswithsleep {
  eval {
    alarm(3600);
    &tracing (8, " .... Meeeep ....");
    alarm(0); 
  };
}


sub lockDBTables {
  return (0) unless ($isdbMySQLconnect);
  my $stm = qq {
    LOCK TABLES 
      myBIGtable WRITE
  };

  my $timeout = 60;          # This is the timer set to protect against deadlocks. Bail out then.
  eval { 
    my $h = set_sig_handler( 'ALRM', sub { my $canceled = 1; die; }, { mask=>[ qw( INT ALRM ) ] ,safe => 0 } ); 
    alarm($timeout); 
    my $res = $dbmyh->do($stm) + 0;
    alarm(0);  # Reset alarm
  };

  if ( $@ =~ m/Die/i ) {
    $isdbTabledlocked = 0;
    &tracerr (0, "FATAL: Lock on Tables has NOT been acquired within ${timeout}s. Lock is set to <$isdbTabledlocked>.");
    &unmesswithsleep();   # MUST be called each time alarm() is used
    return (0);
  } else { 
    $isdbTabledlocked = 1;
    &tracing (2, "  Good: Lock on Tables has been acquired in time. Lock is set to <$isdbTabledlocked>.");
    &unmesswithsleep();   # MUST be called each time alarm() is used
    return (1);
  }
  # Can use sleep() now.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
print "Start\n";
select undef, undef, undef, 1;
print "End\n";
```

This will sleep for 1 second.

Comment: As I mentioned, I have already tried this. I tried select undef, undef, undef, 100; But it doesn't work. Still thank you.

Comment: if your code is being interrupted by a signal then what happens is, unfortunately, system-dependant.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your code that sleeps is being interrupted by some code that sets an alarm. This is by design so you're seeing the expected behavior. In other words an alarm *should always interrupt a sleep call.

If you're looking for a pure perl way to sleep without being interrupted by an alarm you can do this by installing your own alarm signal handler. This way when your code gets an alarm it won't interrupt your processing.

**However, an important caveat is that this will delay any alarm that was set by other code. The other code will receive the alarm late; after your code completes. This means that if you want to play well with others you're better off using one of the other solutions.**

Here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use POSIX;
use strict;
use warnings;

# set an alarm
print "Setting alarm\n";
alarm 1;

my $old_alarm;
my $snoozed;
{
  # store the previous alarm handler (if any)
  $old_alarm = $SIG{ALRM};

  # override the alarm handler so that we don't
  # get interrupted
  local $SIG{ALRM} = sub {
    print "got alarm; snoozing\n";

    # record the fact that we caught an alarm so that
    # we can propagate it when we're done
    $snoozed++;
  };

  # sleep for a while.
  for (1 .. 3) {
    print "z" x $_ ,"\n";
    sleep 1;
  }
}

# replace the old sleep handler;
$SIG{ALRM} = $old_alarm
 if $old_alarm;

# if we had to snooze fire an immediate alarm;
if ($snoozed) {
  POSIX::raise(POSIX::SIGALRM);
}
```

The documentation you reference hints at but does not describe a different symptom. The main thing you need to worry about when sleep is implemented via alarm is having your alarm reset when someone calls sleep.

*Apparently there are some versions of perl (e.g.: old Win32) where an alarm doesn't interrupt sleep.

Comment: Since you mention Windows, `sleep` is about the only thing the `alarm` emulation will interrupt on Windows.

Comment: @ikegami, thanks. I wasn't able to verify it myself. My Win32 comment was a disclaimer about alarm interrupting sleep based on what I found at this OLD perlmonks post http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=300273 and its parent thread.